# Using git version control for PHP development

Tags: php, mysql, git, apache, version-control

Is it possible to version control a PHP + MySQL + Apache project? And could it keep track of the changes in the database, like for example if I added a new table, can I possibly commit that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not normal to keep databases in version control. Some developers use a sqlite database for development so that it can be checked into version control, but this can lead to issues as sqlite syntax can be different from MySQL.

However, you can keep your database schema and migrations source control. Look at a projects such as [mysql-php-migrations](https://github.com/davejkiger/mysql-php-migrations) to get started.

There's a good tutorial on using PHP with Git at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/easy-version-control-with-git/ - this should get you started.

Comment: +1, liking the tutorial to net tuts & advice re: databases in Source control.

Comment: -1 Database schemas should always be under version control. It is normal and necessary.

Comment: @awm - That's exactly what I said. Why have you downvoted me for it?!

Comment: @IHID: "It is not normal to keep databases in version control."

Comment: @awm: It is NOT normal to keep the database in version control. It IS normal to keep the database SCHEMA in version control. That's what I say above... You think it's normal to keep an actual database (e.g. SQLite file that I refer to) in version control?

Comment: @IHID Then change your comments to refer to the database files, not the database.  I'm not going to argue with you over comments.

Answer (score 3):

Using Git for your PHP scripts is no problem, however tracking changes to the database is a little trickier. If you have SQL scripts that create the database structure then these can be version controlled with no problems. Otherwise you could use `mysqldump` to output the structure to an SQL script after any changes you make:

```
mysqldump -d -h localhost -u root -pmypassword mydatabase > dumpfile.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use git to track PHP scripts and SQL scripts that create the necessary database structure. Those SQL scripts could of course be version controlled and recreate the database schema at any given state.

Comment: ah, faster by a split-second ;)

Answer (score 0):

Git is essentially SCM, which means **Source** Control. Tables in mysql are stored as binary files, so it isn't very good idea.

You can, however, store SQL queries which **create** these tables, allowing you to re-create them if you needed to.

As for php, it will be all good.

Answer (score 0):

I recently released a really simple shell script that will help keep changes to a MySQL database under version control.

https://github.com/stevecomrie/mysql-version-control